# React/Redux unable to set a state from a component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple react-redux set up which is described below from which I want to set my state. However I am always getting undefined.

> DashBoard Component

```
class DashBoard extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: 'b',
          rooms: []
        };
    }

    render() {
      return (
         <div onClick={this.handleChange}>Click it</div>
      )
    }

    handleChange = (value) => {
      this.setState({
        value: value,
      });
      axios.get('http://localhost:3001/rooms').
        then((res) => {
        this.props.setRooms(res.data.rooms);
        console.log(this.props.rooms)
      }).
      catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    };
}
```

Very simple component. Now I have my dispatch and exports set up like this

```
onst mapDispatchToProps = dispatch  => {
    return bindActionCreators({ setRooms }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(DashBoard);
```

My room reducer looks like this

```
import {SET_ROOMS} from '../actions/index';

function rooms_reducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_ROOMS:
            return action.rooms;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default rooms_reducer;
```

And finally my action looks like this.

```
export function setRooms(rooms) {
    const action = {
        type: SET_ROOMS,
        rooms
    }
    return action;
}
```

Now I can't really seem to find why this.props.rooms in the control log is returning undefined. A little help would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: I don't see `mapStateToProps`. This function map redux store to component props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass mapStateToProps to your connect:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ rooms })  => ({ rooms })

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch  => {
   return bindActionCreators({ setRooms }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashBoard);
```

because you're saving the rooms in your state but you're not actually passing it back as props to the component, and it doesn't happen automatically

Answer (score 1):

You aren't able to see the Redux store values because you haven't passed it on to the component. You should use mapStateToProps function for this purpose.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
       rooms: state.rooms
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(DashBoard);
```

Also since updating the store is an async action, you won't see the result immediately after dispatching the action